# Classicality theorems for Hilbert eigenforms of low weight

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $p$ be a prime, $k \geq 2$ an integer and $f$ a normalized overconvergent, cuspidal eigenform of finite slope, weight $k$, and level divisible by $p$. The classicality theorem of Coleman gives says that $f$ is classical exactly if $\mathrm{val}_p(a_p(f))<k-1$ or if $\mathrm{val}_p(a_p(f))=k-1$ and $f$ is not in the image of the $k-1$ iteration of the operator $\theta = qd/dq$.

Now suppose instead that $f$ is a Hilbert modular form of partial weight $1$. For simplicity, let's say $F$ is a totally real field quadratic over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $f$ is normalized overconvergent, cuspidal Hilbert eigenform for $F$ of finite slope, weight $[k_1,k_2,w]=[k,1,w]$ where $k\geq 2,w\in \mathbb{Z}$, and level divisible by $p$. In this context there are theta operators constructed by Goren and Kassaei, which correspond to the different weights, so let's say $\theta$ is the one corresponding to the first weight $k_1=k$. Is there a similar classicality theorem in this context? (Say, if the slope is small enough compared to an expression involving $k$ and $w$, then $f$ is classical? And perhaps the boundary case has something similar to do with the $\theta$ operator?)

Such a criterion is conjectured by Breuil in section 4 of "conjectures de classicité sur les formes de Hilbert surconvergentes de pente finie" but classicality results I am familiar with (such as in the work of Tian and Xiao) always assume the weight is cohomological.

Thanks!

Comment: I think Stephane Bijankowski's article called Classicite de formes modulaires de Hilbert is maybe what you want. I can't see any restriction on the weight in his theorem and since it does not appear to be a cohomological construction, so it should probably work (note this I think is for geometric hmfs, so you might need to argue a bit more to get your arithmetic hmfs statement).  If not, then I expect you can find it somewhere in the "Arithmetique $p$-adique des formes de Hilbert".